Mbed TLS and LwIP: How to force the client-side connection to be closed?
I have a device (STM32F4 with FreeRTOS, LWIP, MbedTLS) that establishes a TLS connection with a server. I want to keep this connection up all the time for two-way message exchange in time intervals of 30 seconds to 10 minutes. Sometimes I want to close this connection to temporarily free RAM (~40kB) for other tasks. Most of the time the task is blocked on the mbedtls_ssl_read() function.
The question is how to interrupt this TLS connection from another task so as to exit the mbedtls_ssl_read function and free RAM as it happens when the server terminates the connection.
I tried to close connection with the functions:
shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
mbedtls_net_close(net_context);

called from another task. On Wireshark I see that the device (client) sends a FIN, ACK packet, to which the server responds with an ACK packet and nothing else happens. The call stack is identical before and after calling one of the above functions (stack ends with the xQueueGenericReceive() function, as below). The connection is established with the 3rd party custom server see screenshot, but the behavior with the regular https server is very similar see screenshot (4 packets instead of 2).
Before connecting I set the socket timeout
timeOut.tv_sec = 20 * 60;
timeOut.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (void*)&timeOut, sizeof(struct timeval));
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (void*)&timeOut, sizeof(struct timeval));

If I set a short timeout, the connection is terminated, but I don't want the timeout to occur during normal operation.
The TLS task works like this (pseudo code):
loop:
  if(TLS connection enabled)
    prepare TLS structs includes certs (malloc)
    set socket options (timeouts)
    set bio
    handshake
    verify cert
    loop2:
      mbedtls_ssl_read
      mbedtls_ssl_write or exit loop
    mbedtls_ssl_close_notify
    free all allocated structs

Callstack when waiting for data
Thread #5 (Suspended : Container)   
    xQueueGenericReceive() at queue.c
    sys_arch_mbox_fetch() at sys_arch.c
    netconn_recv_data() at api_lib.c
    netconn_recv_data_tcp() at api_lib.c
    netconn_recv_tcp_pbuf_flags() at api_lib.c
    lwip_recv_tcp() at sockets.c
    lwip_recvfrom() at sockets.c
    lwip_read() at sockets.c
    mbedtls_net_recv() at net_sockets.c
    mbedtls_ssl_fetch_input() at ssl_msg.c
    ssl_get_next_record() at ssl_msg.c
    mbedtls_ssl_read_record() at ssl_msg.c
    mbedtls_ssl_read() at ssl_msg.c
    HTTPD_SocketRead() at httpd.c
    HTML_Process() at html.c
    HTTPD_Cloud_Serve() at httpd.c
    Cloud_Task() at acloud.c


From your callstack I see that the function mbedtls_net_recv() is called which normally sets the rcvTimeout to 0 before calling the lwip_setsockopt() for setting the receive timeout.
Instead of using the function mbedtls_net_recv() the function mbedtls_net_recv_timeout() should be used to receive data over TLS with a timeout.
(mbedtls_net_recv_timeout() has to be configured in the TLS setup with mbedtls_ssl_set_bio()).
In your implementation of mbedtls_net_recv_timeout() you have to check if a timeout occurred, as shown in the example code below, and return MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_TIMEOUT):
int mbedtls_net_recv_timeout( void *ctx, unsigned char *buf, size_t len,
                      uint32_t timeout )
{
    int retVal = MBEDTLS_ERR_NET_RECV_FAILED;

    [...]

    int received = lwip_recv(socket, buf, len, 0);

    if(received >= 0)
    {
        retVal = received;
    }
    else
    {
           /* The error code ERR_TIMEOUT returned by the LWIP socket
            * gets converted by the function sock_set_errno() to EWOULDBLOCK.
            * The converted error is stored in errno.
            * Therefore, in this case EWOULDBLOCK corresponds to a socket timeout */
        if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            retVal = MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_TIMEOUT;
        }
    }


    [...]

    return retVal;
}

Now in the task where you are performing the mbedtls_ssl_read() you can wait to receive data or wait for the timeout.
E.g. you can do this in your receive loop:
tlsReceive()
{
    int32_t retVal = 0;
    [...]

    mbedtls_ssl_conf_read_timeout(&tlsConf, timout_ms);

    while(true)
    {
        retVal = mbedtls_ssl_read(sslContext, pBuffer, BufferLen);
        if (retVal > 0)
        {
            sendDataToApplication(pBuffer, retVal);
        }
        else if (retVal == MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_TIMEOUT)
        {
           /* In order to continue reading after a timeout the TLS timer has to be
            * reset otherwise mbedtls_ssl_read will always return timeout error event
            * when the timeout is not yet ellapsed. */
            if (sslContext.f_set_timer != nullptr)
            {
                sslContext.f_set_timer(sslContext.p_timer, 0U, 0U);
            }
            
            /* Here a read timeout occurred. You can break out of the read loop 
             * if desired. 
             * E.g., you can send a TaskNotification to from another task if you want
             * want to stop otherwise you can restart the read. */
             if (xTaskNotifyWait(0, ULONG_MAX, &u32NotifiedValue, 0) == pdTRUE)
             {
                // break out of the read loop and do your close connection stuff
             }

        }
        else if ( (retVal < 0) && 
                 (retVal != MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_WANT_READ) &&
                 (retVal != MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_WANT_WRITE))
        {
            // do error handling
        }
    }
}

